# Magento 2 setShippingMethodsOnCart GraphQL mutation

Tags: magento2, graphql

I am try to implement Paypal Express with PWA, I am refer **https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/graphql/payment-methods/payflow-express.html** link to implement Graphql API. I have completed 1 to 6 steps.
In 7 step i am try to implement `setPaymentMethodOnCart` mutation. In 7 step
As per magento link suggestion we need to pass PayPal token, Payer ID and Cart ID in `setPaymentMethodOnCart` mutation, but when i pass PayPal token, Payer ID to mutation i got the error `Field \"token\" is not defined by type PaymentMethodInput`, In 7 step description magento has mention we need to pass PayPal token, Payer ID in mutation but when i am try to do this i am getting error.

Request :

```
mutation {
  setPaymentMethodOnCart(input: {
      cart_id: "xxxxY2GZeLjGKdC4bea6R8dGFvXfxxxx"
      payment_method: {
          code: "payflow_express"
          token: "xxxx"
          payerid: "xxxx"
      }
  }) {
    cart {
      selected_payment_method {
        code
        title
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Anyone have idea how can we pass Token and Payer Id.

Answer (score 0):

---

payflow_express: {
          payer_id: ""
          token: ""
        }

this is correct format:

```
> mutation {   setPaymentMethodOnCart(input: {
>     cart_id: "rMQdWEecBZr4SVWZwj2AF6y0dNCKQ8uH"
>     payment_method: {
>         code: "payflow_express"
>         payflow_express: {
>           payer_id: "<PayPal_PayerID>"
>           token: "<PayPal_Token>"
>         }
>       }   }) {
>     cart {
>       selected_payment_method {
>         code
>       }
>     }   } }
```